# Cannot read property 'B' of undefined Angular 11.2.12

Tags: javascript, angular

First i created new angular app with `ng new angular` with no stricter type checking, no angular routing and using scss. Then i try to `ng serve` and get error `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'B' of undefined`.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.12",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

angular-error.log file:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'B' of undefined
    at Object.unpackFeature [as feature] (/Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/caniuse-lite/dist/unpacker/feature.js:28:44)
    at BuildBrowserFeatures.isFeatureSupported (/Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/build-browser-features.js:45:37)
    at BuildBrowserFeatures.isEs5SupportNeeded (/Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/build-browser-features.js:31:22)
    at BuildBrowserFeatures.isDifferentialLoadingNeeded (/Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/build-browser-features.js:25:41)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (/Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js:191:60)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:47:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at /Users/mulenokd/sites/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

How can i resolve this error and start my app?

Comment: Check value of object that you call `.B` onto. It's not set - means it's `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Cannot reproduce... Did the exact same and not getting any error

Comment: delete the node_module folder,  then delete package-lock.json, then run 'npm install' and then try running 'npm start', it should fix the problem

Comment: saw same issue on my machine too. I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Un-Install angular globally from Mac: sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2. Delete the newly created angular app.
3. Run the install command again: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
4. Run the command: ng serve
5. Browse your application: http://localhost:4200

This solved my problem on MacBook. if you are using window, do not use sudo before npm command.